# How can I delay my task before it returns?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

My assertion of `acceptor.IsStarted.Should().BeTrue();` (see unit test below) always fails, as it's getting evaluated too early. The call to `await task` returns immediately and doesn't give `this.acceptor.Start()` enough time to spin up.

I would like to make the startup of my `FixAcceptor()` more *deterministic* and therefor introduced the parameter `TimeSpan startupDelay`.

However I simply have no clue where and how I can delay the startup.

Putting an additional `Thread.Sleep(startupDelay)` between `this.acceptor.Start()` and `this.IsStarted = true` won't help as it will only block the worker task itself, but not the calling thread.

I hope it's clear what I'd like to archive and what I am struggling with. Thanks in advance.

```
public class FixAcceptor
{
    // Type provided by QuickFix.net
    private readonly ThreadedSocketAcceptor acceptor;

    public FixAcceptor(IFixSettings settings)
    {
        // Shortened
    }

    public bool IsStarted { get; private set; }

    public async void Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan startupDelay)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            this.acceptor.Start();
            this.IsStarted = true;

            while (true)
            {
                // Stop if token has been canceled
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    this.acceptor.Stop();
                    this.IsStarted = false;

                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                // Save some CPU cycles
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }

        }, cancellationToken);

        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding consumer code

```
[Fact]
public void Should_Run_Acceptor_And_Stop_By_CancelationToken()
{
    // Arrange
    var acceptor = new FixAcceptor(new FixAcceptorSettings("test_acceptor.cfg", this.logger));
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Act
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    acceptor.Run(tokenSource.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    // Assert
    acceptor.IsStarted.Should().BeTrue();
    IsListeningOnTcpPort(9823).Should().BeTrue();

    // Wait for cancel event to occur
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    acceptor.IsStarted.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. There's no reason to use an infinite loop inside a task, a task is supposed to represent the work performed inside that polling loop. In this case though, I suspect that all that's needed is a call to `cancellationToken.Register(()=>acceptor.Stop())`. Even if `acceptor.Start()` blocks, it could be called with `await Task.Run(acceptor.Start);`

Comment: Finally, `async void` is only meant for asynchronous event handlers. It can't be awaited, so there's no way to know if a task has finished or even started. The test code will probably *exit* before the first task had a change to get scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding time delays to achieve determinism is not a recommended practice. You can achieve 100% determinism by using a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) for controlling the completion of a task at just the right moment:

```
public Task<bool> Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var startTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        this.acceptor.Start();
        this.IsStarted = true;
        startTcs.TrySetResult(true); // Signal that the starting phase is completed

        while (true)
        {
            // ...
        }

    }, cancellationToken);
    HandleTaskCompletion();
    return startTcs.Task;

    async void HandleTaskCompletion() // async void method = should never throw
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            startTcs.TrySetResult(false); // Signal that start failed
        }
        catch
        {
            startTcs.TrySetResult(false); // Signal that start failed
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace this line in your test:

```
acceptor.Run(tokenSource.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

...with this one:

```
bool startResult = await acceptor.Start(tokenSource.Token);
```

Another issue that caught my eye is the `bool IsStarted` property which is mutated from one thread and observed by another, without synchronization. This is not really a problem because you could rely on the undocumented memory barrier that is inserted automatically on every `await`, and be quite confident that you'll not have visibility issues, but if you want to be extra sure you could synchronize the access by using a `lock` (most robust), or backup the property with a `volatile` private field like this:

```
private volatile bool _isStarted;
public bool IsStarted => _isStarted;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you structure your `FixAcceptor.Run()` methode a little bit different

```cs
public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan startupDelay)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try 
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            this.acceptor.Start();
            this.IsStarted = true;

            while (true)
            {
                // Stop if token has been canceled
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    this.acceptor.Stop();
                    this.IsStarted = false;

                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                // Save some CPU cycles
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            Debut.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }, cancellationToken);

    await Task.Delay(startupDelay);
}
```

so the exception handling is in the inner task and the `Run` methode returns a `Task` that completes after the `startupDelay`.
(I also exchanged the `Thread.Sleep()` with a `Task.Delay()`)
Then in the test methode you can await the `Task` returned by `Run`

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Run_Acceptor_And_Stop_By_CancelationToken()
{
    // Arrange
    var acceptor = new FixAcceptor(new FixAcceptorSettings("test_acceptor.cfg", this.logger));
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Act
    tokenSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    await acceptor.Run(tokenSource.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    // Assert
    acceptor.IsStarted.Should().BeTrue();
    IsListeningOnTcpPort(9823).Should().BeTrue();

    // Wait for cancel event to occur
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    acceptor.IsStarted.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

It should be okay to make the mehtode `async` (it seams like you use xunit)